# null values are inserted into database together with actual values from jsp form

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, ajax, jsp

I am working on a student registration form such that when a student fills the necessary information using a multi step form and submits, the filled information will be submitted to the database.

However, anytime I submit the filled information, the values will be inserted into the database including another complete row of null values.

I have tried to fix this thing but don't know where the problem is.

This is StudentSignup.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var xmlHttp;
        <%--JavaScript on Academic Information Dropdown Using XmlHttpRequest--%>
        function showDepartment(str) {
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined") {
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (xmlHttp === null) {
                alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request");
                return;
            } else {
                var url = "departmentDBConnection.jsp";
                url += "?progOfStudy=" + str;
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
                xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }
        }

        function stateChange() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 || xmlHttp.readyState === "complete") {
                document.getElementById("department").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText
                        ;
            }
        }

        function showFaculty(str) {
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined") {
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();//create XMLHttpRequest object
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (xmlHttp === null) {//If the browser doesn't support Ajax, exit now
                alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request");
                return;
            } else {
                var url = "facultyDBConnection.jsp";
                url += "?progOfStudy=" + str;
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange1;
                xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);//Initiate the XMLHttpRequest object
                xmlHttp.send(null);//Send the Ajax request to the server with the GET data
            }

            function stateChange1() {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 || xmlHttp.readyState === "complete") {
                    document.getElementById("faculty").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText
                            ;
                }
            }
        }

    </script>  

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StudentSignUp.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Student Login</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="wrapper"> 
        <div id="headwrap">
            <header> 
                <h1>School Name</h1>
                <h3>Knowledge for development and unity</h3>

            </header> 
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></li>             
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <img src="images/kasulogo.jpg" />
        </div>

    </div>


    <aside id="logsite">
        <center>
            <!--form name="form1" id="regForm" action="StudentCreateAccount.jsp"-->

            <!--form id="regForm" method="post"  onSubmit="submitForm(this);return false;"-->    
            <form id="regForm" >

                <table cellspacing="5" border="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2" ><b><center id="CreateHead">Create a New Account</center></b></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><hr/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
                </table>
                <div class="tab"><b><center>Personal Information:</center></b>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><hr/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Matriculation*</td>
                            <td><input placeholder="" oninput="this.className = ''" name="MatricNo" required=""></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>First Name*</td>
                            <td><input placeholder="" oninput="this.className = ''" name="FName" required=""></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Last Name*</td>
                            <td><input placeholder="" oninput="this.className = ''" name="LName" required=""></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Other Names</td>
                            <td><input placeholder="" oninput="this.className = ''" name="OName"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Email Address</td>
                            <td><input placeholder="" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Email"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Phone Number*</td>
                            <td><input placeholder="" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Phone"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="tab"><b><center>Academic Information:</center></b>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><hr/></td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Programme*</td>
                            <!-- <td><p><input placeholder="" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Department"></p></td> -->
                            <td><p>


                                    <select name='ProgOfStudy' onchange="showDepartment(this.value)">  
                                        <option value="none">--Select Programme--</option>  
                                        <%

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                            Connection con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cmsdb", "root", "");
                                            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from programmeofstudy");
                                            while (rs.next()) {
                                        %>
                                        <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>  
                                        <%

                                            }


                                        %>

                                    </select>                                        
                                <p></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Department*</td>
                            <td><p>

                                <div id='department'>
                                    <select name='Department' >  
                                        <option value='-1'>--Select Department--</option>  
                                    </select>  
                                </div>

                                <p></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Faculty*</td>
                            <td><p>
                                <div id='faculty'>  
                                    <select name='Faculty' >  
                                        <option value='-1'>--Select Faculty--</option>  
                                    </select>  
                                </div>

                                <p></td>
                        </tr>


                    </table>
                </div>  

                <div class="tab"><b><center>Login Info:</center></b>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><hr/></td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>


                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password*</td>
                            <td><input type="password" placeholder="" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Password"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Retype Password*</td>
                            <td><input type ="password" placeholder="" oninput="this.className = ''" name="rePassword" oninput="setCustomValidity(value != password1.value ? 'Passwords do not match.' : '')"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div style="overflow:auto;">
                    <div style="float:right;">
                        <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                        <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
                <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
                    <span class="step"></span>
                    <span class="step"></span>
                    <span class="step"></span>

                </div>
            </form>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
                showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

                function showTab(n) {
                    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
                    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
                    x[n].style.display = "block";
                    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
                    if (n === 0) {
                        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
                    }
                    if (n === (x.length - 1)) {
                        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
                    }
                    //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
                    fixStepIndicator(n);
                }

                function nextPrev(n) {
                    // This function will figure out which tab to display
                    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
                    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
                    if (n === 1 && !validateForm())
                        return false;
                    // Hide the current tab:
                    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
                    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
                    currentTab = currentTab + n;
                    // if you have reached the end of the form...
                    if (currentTab >= x.length) {

                        var frm = document.getElementById('regForm');
                        //var frm = new formData;alert(frm.MatricNo.value);
                        var MatNo = frm.MatricNo.value;//alert("MatNo is: "+MatNo);
                        var FName = frm.FName.value;
                        var LName = frm.LName.value;
                        var OName = frm.OName.value;
                        var eMail = frm.Email.value;
                        var phone = frm.Phone.value;
                        var pwd = frm.Password.value;

                        var storedTextProgOfStudy = frm.ProgOfStudy.options[frm.ProgOfStudy.selectedIndex].text;
                        var storedTextDepartment = frm.Department.options[frm.Department.selectedIndex].text;
                        var storedTextFaculty = frm.Faculty.options[frm.Faculty.selectedIndex].text;
                        //alert(storedTextProgOfStudy +" "+ " "+ storedTextDepartment +" "+storedTextFaculty +" "+MatNo);  



                        var url = "StudentCreateAccount.jsp";
                        var parameters = "ProgOfStudy=" + storedTextProgOfStudy + '&Department=' + storedTextDepartment + '&Faculty=' + storedTextFaculty +
                                "&MatricNo=" + MatNo + "&FName=" + FName + "&LName=" + LName + "&OName=" + OName + "&Email=" + eMail + "&Phone=" + phone + "&Password=" + pwd;

                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open("GET", url + "?" + parameters, true);
                        xhr.send(null);

                        window.location = url;

                    }
                    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
                    showTab(currentTab);
                }

                function validateForm() {
                    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
                    var x, y, i, valid = true;
                    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
                    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
                    // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
                    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                        // If a field is empty...
                        if (y[i].value === "") {
                            // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                            y[i].className += " invalid";
                            // and set the current valid status to false
                            valid = false;
                        }
                    }
                    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
                    if (valid) {
                        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
                    }
                    return valid; // return the valid status
                }

                function fixStepIndicator(n) {
                    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
                    var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
                    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                    }
                    //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
                    x[n].className += " active";
                }
            </script>
        </center>
    </aside>

    <footer>
        <br />
        &copy; 2018 . All right reserved.
    </footer> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the StudentCreateAccount.jsp

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>

<%
Connection conn = null;

        String matNo = request.getParameter("MatricNo");
        String FName = request.getParameter("FName");
        String LName = request.getParameter("LName");
        String OName = request.getParameter("OName");
        String email = request.getParameter("Email");
        String phoneNo = request.getParameter("Phone");
        String programmeOfStudy = request.getParameter("ProgOfStudy");
        String department = request.getParameter("Department");
        String faculty = request.getParameter("Faculty");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("Password");
        //String retypePwd = request.getParameter("rePassword");


        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cmsdb";
        String rootUser = "root";
        String rootPwd = "";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";



        Class.forName(driver); //This loads the driver for the database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, rootUser, rootPwd);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();


        ResultSet rs;

        //This is the SQL String for retrieving data by name from the database.
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kasustudent WHERE MatricNo='" + matNo +"'");            


        if(rs.next()){   

            out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            out.println("alert('Matric Number already exist in the Database!');");
            out.println("location='StudentLogin.jsp';");
            out.println("</script>");

        }else{

        String query = "INSERT INTO kasustudent(MatricNo, FName, LName, ONames, Email, Phone, CourseOfStudy, Department, Faculty, Password) "
                + "VALUES ('" + matNo + "','" + FName + "','" + LName + "','" + OName + "','" + email + "','" + phoneNo + "','" 
                + programmeOfStudy + "','" + department + "','" + faculty + "','" + pwd + "')";

        st.executeUpdate(query);

            out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            out.println("alert('Account Successfully Created!!\\nLogin to access your Dashboard!');");
            out.println("location='StudentLogin.jsp';");
            out.println("</script>");

        st.close();

    }
%>
```

Please assistance is highly appreciated.
Apologies to bore you with so much codes.

Even when the StudentCreateAccount.jsp (scriptlet) file is run, the null values will be inserted into the database.

Please, critically look into the codes and tell me the problem is?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: so I would guess that `rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kasustudent WHERE MatricNo='" + matNo +"'"); ` would return no records so the `else` part would execute - **BUT** if this was written using MVC paradigm where JSP is for `V`iewing stuff and not business logic, you could this code in a servlet where you could easily debug in.

Comment: could you also show a screenshot of these nulls you're noticing?

Comment: Side note: never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input, not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: @Scary Wombat Thank you for your response. I think your explain is correct however, whenever I submit the filled multi step form, the values are correctly inserted including a row of null values. The implication is that I cannot insert another value since the `MatricNo` column cannot receive duplicate values. 
I dont know about the MVC paradigm, if you could either help me structure my codes using the paradigm or give me link to the resources. Thank you in anticipation @ScaryWombat

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere how do I post the screenshot here in the comment section? If you know it, can you tell me.
But I can show you the table structure:
`CREATE TABLE kasustudent (`MatricNo` VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL, `FName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `LName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `ONames` VARCHAR(45), `Email` VARCHAR(45), `Phone` VARCHAR(15), `Faculty` VARCHAR(70), `Department` VARCHAR(70), `CourseOfStudy` VARCHAR(50), `Level` VARCHAR(10), `Session` VARCHAR(10), `Semester` INT, `CourseCode` VARCHAR(8), `Password` VARCHAR(45), PRIMARY KEY (`MatricNo`));`

I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Thank you for the side note @JozefChocholacek. I will note it very well.

Comment: The screenshot would go into your question.

Comment: You could try studying this https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/

Comment: Hi  guys after carefully going through your advise, I eventually figured out the problem. The client side was actually calling the page while sending null parameters to it. Many thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Thanks @ScaryWombat for the link also.

Comment: Thanks @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere

Comment: Thanks @JozefChocholacek, implemented your observations too..